# How to enter router configuration webpage

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I have a Wifi router Tp-Link TL-WR740N

I need it to work as bridge, so I plugged the WAN to a common LAN port, and **disabled the router DHCP**

Before disabling it, I configured the Wifi network(SSID, password, security type)

It works as intended. All LAN and Wifi devices are bridged to the WAN (Internet also comes from the WAN)

But I no more can access the Wifi router webpage, and cannot find any instruction on how to enter the router webpage.

I have no way to know if the router has an IP assigned, and I cannot find it on the network.

There is any way to find the router webpage, or his IP? (other than resetting the router to manufacturer settings)

Comment: Try to scan your network for devices with software. You can use ["advanced IP scanner"](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) You should be able to find the device's ip address.

Comment: I'd add, when you do sort it out - its a great idea to set a static IP on the router. Also windows 7 had a great network mapping tool which could be useful here, and the simplest way to solve the problem - *if* you have a windows 7 system handy

Comment: WIndows 7 can't do anything because the DHCP is disabled, and so is UPnP which it uses to display those fancy router icons in network neighborhood. The router does have a static IP address - indeed, the only option it provides - but it is probably not accessible without explicit configuration since new DHCP server probably advertises a different network.

Answer (score 1):

The WiFi router address will be whatever the DHCP server assigned to it. You should be able to hop onto the main router to see a list of connected devices and get the address there.

Comment: This will most likely not work. This router has two networks - WAN and LAN. As per manual, it does not support getting its IP-address from DHCP-server on LAN side. It does support DHCP on WAN side, but unless manually configured otherwise it should prevent access using WAN-side IP-address. Thus it needs to be accessed using LAN static IP-address as outlined in my answer. I may be wrong if a software update added LAN DHCP support, that update was installed, and the feature was enabled; latest firmware release-notes have no mention of such a feature.

Answer (score -1):

Connect your computer to any LAN ports of your router, or connect to its wireless network. Make sure the router is working.

You have not specified what OS you have installed on your computer, so I assume Windows. If it is anything else please refer to OS documentation on how to complete the steps below.

### Obtain LAN configuration

If you remember what IP-address was configured on router's `Network → LAN` web administration settings page, proceed to next step.

Factory defaults are: IP address = `192.168.0.1`, subnet mask = `255.255.255.0` - try those before anything else.

---

If you do not remember what was configured, you have three options:

1. Factory-reset the router
2. Use your router vendor's utility to find router's IP-address
3. Try to find its IP-address in ARP cache like this:

   - Write down MAC-address that is printed on the bottom of the router. It should be a hexadecimal number like `F4F26D123456` or `F4-F2-6D-12-34-56`. [image]
   - [Open command prompt](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-2618089) (On Unix-like OS this is called a terminal emulator) by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, typing `cmd`, and hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.
   - Type `arp -a` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This commands displays ARP MAC-to-IP table like this:

   Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
   192.168.168.2        00-98-76-54-32-10     dynamic
   192.168.168.3        00-AB-CD-EF-01-23     dynamic

   - Try finding the MAC-address you wrote down in the "physical address" column, router's IP-address should be in "Internet address" column.

If your MAC-address is not listed you could try following:

- Disconnect you computer from all networks except the one connected directly to your router.
- [Assign a static IPv4-address to your computer](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) that does not belong to any local network. Something like `8.7.6.5` should do. Subnet mask should be `0.0.0.0`, no default gateway or DNS-servers. This ensures we are actually sending data to correct network.
- Flush ARP cache by typing following command in command prompt: `arp -d -a` (on Linux: `sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all`) and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Rebooting your computer also works.
- Now we need to broadcast any data to everything on the physical network. To do that input command `ping 255.255.255.255 -n 1` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The command should be unable to receive any respose - that is normal.
- Input command `arp -a` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Examine results once again.

If nothing works, you may want need to resort to guessing IP-address. `192.168.0.1`, `192.168.1.1`, `10.0.0.1`, `192.168.8.1`, `192.168.10.1`, `192.168.100.1`, `192.168.1.100` are the common ones.

### Manually assign IP-address

- Your router does not support obtaining its LAN network address from a DHCP server. To be able to access the router without hassle, configure your DHCP server to reserve any IPv4 address within your network for the router. Your router will never actually query the server, but the server should not assign this address to any other device.
- [Assign a static IPv4-address to your computer](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) that belongs to same network as the router. Simply add 1 to last octet of router's IP address, so if your router's IP address is `192.168.123.1` configure your computer to use `192.168.123.2`. If you do not know the network mask, try `255.255.255.0` or `0.0.0.0`. Leave default gateway and DNS-address fields blank.
- Open a web-browser and browse to your router's IP-address. You should be able to login into its web-administration panel. If connection fails, you probably guessed it's IP address incorrectly.
- Use the web administration panel (Network → LAN) to configure a your router's static address to previously reserved one. Save settings and reboot your router.
- Revert your computer's network configuration to obtain IP-address from DHCP server again.
- You should now be able to log onto your router's web administration panel by connecting to IP-address you reserved without re-configuring your computer to do so .